# Godot: MultiMesh deletes itself when created by script

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm making a game in Godot and decided to use MultiMesh to load groups of objects. However, every time a create a new instance of the object, [it deletes itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aix9k.png) and just shows as 'empty' on the inspector. I've also tried loading a resource from a file and that works fine but when I duplicate it, the same thing happens.

I have no idea why this is happening, I'm probably miss understanding how resources work, though the documentation shows an example where they use 'MultiMesh.new()'. If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong, please say because I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: Please share a [minimal, complete, and reproduceable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide a script. In which place you create mesh? Maybe place is wrong, and data are destroyed.